# How to convert hex into dec string in C++?

Tags: c++, string, utf-8, hex, decimal

I'm using C++11. Is there a function that gets the string of hex and turns it into decimal?

I've tried to find something about `unicode()` function that I saw somewhere in StackOverflow, but I couldn't find any information about it.

For example, we have a symbol hex: `U+03C0`. How to turn it into dec: `960`?

Let's imagine this:

```
char* pi_symbol = hexToDec("U+03C0");
cout << "The pi dec is " << pi_symbol << endl;
```

And get this:

> The pi dec is 960

Comment: FWIW, lower case pi is `U+03C0`.

Comment: @NathanOliver fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`std::hex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
int main()
{
    int n;
    std::istringstream("03C0") >> std::hex >> n;
    std::cout << n;
}
```

Comment: Could you please give me an example how to use `std::hex` since I don't really get it.

Comment: @EadwineYoun there is one in the link

Comment: @EadwineYoun check this live link https://wandbox.org/permlink/qm8rj1sBIroRjqsT

Comment: Hm, why does it give us `3C0` instead of `U+03C0`?

Comment: Because `U+03C0` is not hex.  It's a representation of a Unicode value.  Strictly, hex just means base 16.  For example the `0x` prefix to `0x3C0`  just is syntax sugar that provide so we can differentiate between base 16, 8, 10 values (C/C++ context).  Glossing over details, the simple answer: The `U+` prefix is not a prefix to indicate hexadecimal-ness.  It's a prefix to indicate possible Unicode-ness.   Slice off the U+, then interpret the value (the  hex number).

Comment: @jdw thanks for explaining. I really appreciate that :)